# Convert String to Int in Firebase

Tags: javascript, string, firebase-realtime-database, int

Currently, I have the following data stored in my database

```
"-L1KjJ81Vj0QcDT7RCiG" : {
  "Date": "475748948575"
}
```

The javascript code that creates this string is as follows:

```
var d = Date.parse(input.dt);

input.dt = Wed, 10 Jan 2018 15:03:00 GMT <-- This is example of data

d is pushed to Date in firebase
```

As you can see the data is a string, however, I would like to convert it to a number is their anyway to do that in Firebase? Please note that I would like any Date being stored is always stored as a number, not a string.

Comment: It seems like you have some code that stored this data. Can you update your question to include that code? That will also answer the question of what technology you're using. :-)

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen edits made

Comment: The code you shared doesn't explain to me where a string with that format would come from. Please show actual compilable code, not pseudo-code. E.g. if you're reading from a form, use a hard-coded value to substitute that. In general, read about [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Make sure the code works, so that we don't have to worry about intentions. One way to do that is to reproduce the problem in a tool like jsbin/jsfiddle.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen there is nothing else to show I convert the date show above to a millisecond value using the Date.Parse function and the result of that function is pushed to Firebase. There is literally nothing else to show,